# UICollectionView equivalent on Mac OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, uicollectionview, osx-yosemite

I have an iPad app that uses the `UICollectionView` containing a label to display string items from an array. I am now working on creating the app for OSX but I am not sure how to do this or what I should use.

It there an equivalent for the Mac?

Answer (score 5):

Apple added a ton of features to NSCollectionView in OS X 10.11 El Capitan (e.g. `NSCollectionViewDataSource`, `NSCollectionViewDelegate` and `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`. It can now almost be used like UICollectionView.

There was a dedicated talk about it at WWDC 2015: [What's New in NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-225/)

They also created an Objective-C sample project: [CocoaSlideCollection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaSlideCollection/Introduction/Intro.html)

I created a simple sample project in Swift: [CollectionViewElCapitan](https://github.com/klaas/CollectionViewElCapitan)

**Updated to Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4:** [CollectionViewSwift4](https://github.com/klaas/CollectionViewSwift4)

Comment: Most excellent.
For a more complicated demo/example (from the Apple Mothership) take a peek at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Exhibition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016178-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Nice example, Klaas. I think it's worth mentioning that you didn't need to make your own view subclass. Since NSCollectionViewItem is a subclass of NSViewController, you can link elements in the nib directly to its outlets. NSCollectionViewItem has a convenience outlet for a text field and an image view so you don't need to make your own outlets for these. You don't need LabelObject either - since all it's doing is wrapping a string, just use a String.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it but a quick google shows an NSCollectionView class. From the Apple docs:

> Before using the NSCollectionView class, you must have an existing
>   window-based Cocoa Application in Xcode. You start by creating a model
>   class in your application, which will store all of the data for each
>   individual object that you wish to display. Then, in Interface
>   Builder, you add a collection view and an array controller to your
>   project. You will also create an array that will store the various
>   objects you wish to display, and to ensure that everything remains in
>   sync, you will create various bindings between the collection view,
>   the array controller, and the array. When you are finished, your
>   collection view will display all of your objects in an organized
>   manner.

Of particular note is the use of Cocoa Bindings. Agan, from Apple docs:

> The Cocoa bindings feature enables you to establish a live connection
>   between an item of data and its presentation in a view. Any change
>   made to the data’s value, either in the view or in the object that
>   stores the data, automatically propagates across the connection.
>
> Using Cocoa bindings reduces the glue code you once had to write to
>   connect a view to its underlying model. Interface Builder, part of
>   Xcode, lets you quickly establish Cocoa bindings.

Answer (score 1):

[JNWCollectionView](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView) is a modern collection view for the Mac. Anyone familiar with `UICollectionView` should feel right at home.

Comment: Have you used JNWCollectionView? I cloned the project to my local machine but when running the APP below data source method is not called.

(JNWCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JNWCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Thanks..one more query can we implement Drag and drop through it